# How do I create a Map type that allows multiple types for both keys and values?

Tags: scala, manifest

I would like to create a Map type so something like the below is possible:

```
VariantMap(1) = "Test"
VariantMap("a") = 42
```

and `VariantMap("a")` would have a type of `Option[Int]`.  Here is the code I have so far which results in `Option[Nothing]`:

```
object VariantMap {
  import scala.reflect.Manifest

  private var _map= Map.empty[Any,(Manifest[_], Any)] 

  def update[T](name: Any, item: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) {
    _map = _map(name) = (m, item)
  }

  def apply[T](key:Any)(implicit m : Manifest[T]) = {
    val o = _map.get(key)

    o match {
      case Some((om: Manifest[_], s : Any)) => Some[T](s.asInstanceOf[T])
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

I'm new to scala so I apologize if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Is there a fixed pattern of key / value types? Or do you just have several key types and several value types, with any of the former being associated with any of the latter? Or is it just anything to anything? In that case, just use Map[Any, Any] and use a match as type-case on the values coming out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether it is directly possible to do what you want. The apply method takes a type parameter [T], but if you don't specify it, the compiler doesn't know what type T exactly  represents. In this case it infers Nothing, the subtype of any other type.

Using your code, supplying a type parameter gives the following result:

```
scala> VariantMap[Int]("a")
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> VariantMap[String]("a")
res1: Option[String] = Some(1)
```

So now, any type is ok, not exactly perfect either. 
You can slightly improve on it with the following variation:

```
object VariantMap {
   import scala.reflect.Manifest

   private var _map= Map.empty[Any,(Manifest[_], Any)] 

   def update[T](name: Any, item: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) {
      _map = _map(name) = (m, item)
   }

   def apply[T](key:Any)(implicit m : Manifest[T]): Option[T] = {
     val o = _map.get(key)      
     o match {
       case Some((om: Manifest[_], s : Any)) => if (om  None
     }
  }
}

scala> VariantMap("a")
res0: Option[Nothing] = None

scala> VariantMap[Int]("a")
res1: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> VariantMap[String]("a")
res2: Option[String] = None
```

Which probably is also not really what you wanted (this just a type safe map), but I don't really see a better solution at this moment.